# i couldn't find s:datespinner component in flash builder 4.6 Flex 4.6

Tags: date, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

i couldn't find s:datespinner component in flash builder 4.6. it uses flex 4.6

i tried the below code

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
>                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
>       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955">
>                   minHeight="600">
>
>    <s:DateSpinner x="491" y="252"/>
>    </s:Application>
> ```

It shows the below error

"Could not resolve  to a component implementation"

Thanks in advance fr your help!!

Answer (score 0):

`spark.components.DateSpinner` is an AIR-only component in the latest SDK, and `s:Application` is going to use the web portion of the framework. If you are trying to make a mobile app, I think you need to use the `ViewNavigatorApplication` or `TabbedViewNavigatorApplication`.

You can see the supported runtimes [here](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/DateSpinner.html) under **Runtime Versions**